# JS: writing a function that has an input of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to input an array of arrays, but then pick them apart. so for example I have an array of locations so like multiple coordinates of latitude and longitude.
but I want to write a loop that will then take that array of arrays and make and array for all of the latitude coordinates and all of the longitude coordinates.

so for example if I had

input = [[45,45],[35,75][85,90]]
it would make 2 arrays as my output
[45,35,85]
and
[45,75,90]

Comment: What is your your question? Where are you having problems?

Comment: What you are looking for is a thing called `zip`, or `zipWith`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the array and take `lat` and `long` as single arrays.

```js
var input = [[45, 45], [35, 75], [85, 90]],
    [lat, long] = input.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => (r[i] || []).concat(v)), []);
    
console.log(lat);
console.log(long);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, loops over every coordinate and puts the first value from each coordinate into the array called `first` and the second value from each coordinate into an array called `second` ..

```
var input = [[45,45],[35,75],[85,90]];

function splitValues(coordinates) {
    var first = [];
    var second = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    first.push(coordinates[i][0]);
    second.push(coordinates[i][1]);
  }
}

splitValues(input);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help assuming you will always have a 2 values array in input and you want only 2 results

```
const array = [[45,45],[35,75],[85,90]]
let first = []
let second = []
array.forEach((item)=>{
    first.push(item[0])
  second.push(item[1])
})
console.log(first)
console.log(second)
```